# (Vue Router) Push params when on a certain route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a component, which has programmatic routing based on external data.
The external data is fetched in the `App.vue` component and used in child components as `props`.

The data is used in the child component like this:

```js
props: {
    externalData: Array
},
computed() {
    data() {
        return this.externalData
    }
}
```

Here is my `router.js` (excerpt)

```js
const routes = [
{
  path: "/:hae?",
  name: "Home",
  component: Home
},
{
  path: "*",
  name: "NotFound",
  component: NotFound
}
];
```

And my `Home.vue` with the `$router.push` method (excerpt):

```js
created() {
  if (this.$route.path === "/") {
    this.$router.push({
      params: {
        hae: this.data[0].id
      }
    });
  }
},
```

So here is what i want to achieve:

This is my example array: `[{hae: "hae001"}, {hae: "hae002"}, {hae: "hae003"} ...]`
When you navigate to `https://website.com/` i want the router to redirect you to a param which is the first element of the array, but if you navigate to somewhere else which is not existing in the array (e.g. `/something`) i want the router to render my `NotFound.vue` component.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
created() {
  const firstDataElementExists = this.data && this.data[0] && this.data[0].hae
  if (!firstDataElementExists) {
        this.$router.push('/404')
        return
  }

  const isRootPath = this.$route.path === '/'
  if (isRootPath) {
    this.$router.push(this.data[0].hae)
    return
  } 

  const pathIsInData = !!this.data.find(d => d.hae === p)
  if (!isRootPath && !pathIsInData) {
    this.$router.push('/404')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problems with the params! Any suggestion for the NotFound component?